# Google Apps Script API call returns "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" need it to return empty field

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to pull some info on Chromebook devices using the Google API. I know some devices will not have recent users, so I expect that field to be blank.
When I included the lines for the device.recentUsers[0].email it went go for a bit and then when it hit an "undefined" it stopped and gave this message "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" - I changed the field to "device.recentUsers" to see what that returned and it shows the whole field is "undefined".

Google API documentation defines the "whole" field as below I only need the email bit, so "device.recentUsers[0].email"

```
"recentUsers": [
    {
      "type": string,
      "email": string
    }
```

How can I get the email field to return as simply "empty"?  I ran a test to pull the first three columns and the "device.recentUsers" without the "[0].mail" bit. From the results, I could get the count of the "undefined" lines. So I know the total record count and the expected breakdown of how many of those should have blank emails.

Checking the fields for content like this

```
if ((device.status == 'ACTIVE') && (device.recentUsers) && (device.activeTimeRanges)) {
```

limits the output and I do not want to make two calls to the database if I can avoid it.
Doing something like this returned a syntax error

```
          if (device.recentUsers) {
            device.recentUsers[0].email,
          } else {
            device.recentUsers = 'BLANK',
          }
```

My script is here with the if statement mentioned above uncommented it works great, but I need the other rows too!

```
function listDevices() {

  var deviceArray = [];
  var pageToken;
  var page;
  do {
      page = AdminDirectory.Chromeosdevices.list(
      'my_customer',
      {
      maxResults: 100,
      pageToken: pageToken
      });

    var devices = page.chromeosdevices;
      if (devices) {
        for (i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
        var device = devices[i];
          //if ((device.status == 'ACTIVE') && (device.recentUsers) && (device.activeTimeRanges)) {
          var row = [
            device.serialNumber,
            device.annotatedAssetId,
            device.status,
            device.recentUsers[0].email,
            device.activeTimeRanges[0].date
            ];
            //Logger.log(device.serialNumber,device.annotatedAssetId,device.status,device.recentUsers[0].email, device.activeTimeRanges[0].date);
          deviceArray.push(row);
          // } 
        } 
      }  
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
  if (deviceArray.length > 0) {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create('TEST Device List');
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

     // Append the headers.
    var headers = ['SerialNo', 'AssetTag', 'Status', 'LastUserEmail', 'LastDate'];
    sheet.appendRow(headers);

    // Append the results.
    sheet.getRange(2, 1, deviceArray.length, headers.length).setValues(deviceArray);

    Logger.log('TEST Device List spreadsheet created: %s', spreadsheet.getUrl());
 } else {
    Logger.log('No results returned.');
  }
}
```

Comment: I figured out how to handle this. I using the typeof() function.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to handle this using the typeof() function. I modified the above code if statement that I had commented out to this:

```
if ((devices.length < i) || (typeof(device.recentUsers)=='undefined') || (typeof(device.activeTimeRanges)=='undefined')) {
   var row = [
      device.serialNumber,
      device.annotatedAssetId,
      device.status,
      '',
      ''
   ];
} else {
    var row = [
      device.serialNumber,
      device.annotatedAssetId,
      device.status,
      device.recentUsers[0].email,
      device.activeTimeRanges[0].date
   ];          
} 
deviceArray.push(row);
```